# Creating text node results in [object HTMLSpanElement], why?

Tags: javascript, html

Why am I not getting time in local format inside the span with the timestamp class?

```js
var modifiedField = document.querySelector(".modified");
var modifiedFieldContent = "Modified: <span class=\"timestamp\"></span";
modifiedField.innerHTML = modifiedFieldContent;

var updatedTime = new Date();
var timestamp = modifiedField.querySelector(".timestamp");
timestamp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(timestamp.toLocaleString()));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="modified"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `modifiedField.querySelector(".timestamp")` returns a Node (the `<span>` element) and not its content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `toLocaleString()` on `timestamp` variable, which is an HTML element, instead of the `updatedTime` variable.

Try:

```js
var modifiedField = document.querySelector(".modified");
var modifiedFieldContent = "Modified: <span class=\"timestamp\"></span";
modifiedField.innerHTML = modifiedFieldContent;

var updatedTime = new Date();
var timestamp = modifiedField.querySelector(".timestamp");
timestamp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(updatedTime.toLocaleString()));
```

```html
<div class="modified"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, I was renaming some variables in my code and forgot this one! What's even worse is that I was staring at the code like 10 mins and couldn't see it. :D Thank you

Comment: 10 mins is still not that much :). Happy to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong variable.
You need

```
timestamp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(updatedTime.toLocaleString()));
```

How about this though:

```
document.querySelector(".modified").innerHTML = "Modified: " + new Date().toLocaleString();
```

Answer (score -1):

First you forgot the span closing '>'`var modifiedFieldContent = "Modified: <span class=\"timestamp\"></span";`, then you have to call `toLocaleString()` on you `updatedTime`, not on your `timestamp` which is an Element.